# Is there a way to cancel a ready to publish app version in "Publishing Overview"

Tags: android, google-play-console

I need to remove or cancel a prod version in the "Publishing Overview". I don't need to overwrite it with a new upload.

Comment: Google Play removes the old version automatically after a new version is published, this is considered a new update and not a new full version

Comment: Okay, I'll just update it. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went to Google Play Academy and did a course on Managed Publishing. From there this was an FAQ:[image]

So, it seems that any APK will be replaced based on the latest version code. For example, if you have an app in 'Changes ready to publish' (in Publishing overview) with a version code 1 then you can replace said app with version code 2. The latest version will override the one in 'Changes ready to publish' and only version code 2 will ever be published to the Play store.

Reference: https://playacademy.exceedlms.com/student/activity/7035-choose-when-your-app-updates-are-published

Answer (score 1):

There is a walk around that you can use if you REALLY need to do this:

from `Google play Console` > `Production` > chose the release then > go to `Countries/Regions` tab > `Remove Countries/Regions` > remove all countries

By doing this the production release will still be there but not available in any country.

But I recommend uploading a new update.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I might try both. And I did email the google support, the only way is uploading a new update

Comment: This doesn't work.  You can only change the countries supported for ALL production releases, not a single release.  This will remove all versions of your app from availability in all countries.  Except you can't even do that, because you can't remove all countries, you have to leave at least one.

Comment: Also, don't forget that if you submit your app for testing and production at the same time you can't only publish to test, you can only publish ALL changes that are ready.

Comment: Also also, don't forget that you can't cancel a review, so as soon as you submit an app for review, you can only either publish it, upload a new version of your app that's the same as the old version but with an incremented version code, OR publish nothing to any track forever.  Google Play is the worst.